# Prepend command, stdout and stderr

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following code which reads a number of commands, prints them and prints their output.

```
while read line ; do
  echo "C:$line"
  echo "O:$(${line} 2>&1 | perl -pe 's,\n,\\n,'g)\n"
done << EOF
g++-4.8 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
./a.out
EOF
```

Output:

```
C:g++-4.8 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
O:main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:\nmain.cpp:3:9: warning: unused variable ‘unused’ [-Wunused-variable]\n     int unused;\n         ^\n\n
C:./a.out
O:*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff3bd01a5c ***\n======= Backtrace: =========\n/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7f6960e1ab96]\n./a.out[0x400502]\n/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7f6960dbd76d]\n./a.out[0x400535]\n======= Memory map: ========\n\n
```

I would like to distinguish between stdout and stderr and use the 'E:' prefix for stderr. Also I would like to print the exit code of each command line.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just a warning: keep in mind that something like `a.out "a string"` in your here-document may cause your code to break if `a.out` is expecting a single argument. Here, `a.out` would receive 2: `"a` and `string"`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Add a prefix to each line of stdin.
prefix() {
    local line
    while read line; do printf '%s%s\n' "$1" "$line"; done
}

# Execute each command. Notice the `(' and `)' surrounding the loop body, which starts
# a sub-shell for each iteration. Running in a sub-shell lets us use `trap EXIT' to
# cleanup.
while read command; do (
    # Create FIFOs for the command's stdout and stderr.
    stdout=$(mktemp -u)
    stderr=$(mktemp -u)
    mkfifo "$stdout" "$stderr"

    # Delete the FIFOs when this iteration of the loop finishes. Use `trap' to ensure
    # cleanup happens whether we finish normally or are signalled.
    trap 'rm -f "$stdout" "$stderr"' EXIT

    # Read from the FIFOs in the background, adding the desired prefixes.
    prefix 'O:' < "$stdout" >&1 &
    prefix 'E:' < "$stderr" >&2 &

    # Now execute the command, sending its stdout and stderr to the FIFOs.
    echo "C:$command"
    eval "$command" 1> "$stdout" 2> "$stderr"
    exitcode=$?

    # Wait for the `prefix' processes to finish, then print the exit code.
    wait
    echo "R:$exitcode"
    exit $exitcode
) done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my submission. I think it does something similar to John's but seems to have a few less lines. I'm just including it here as an alternative as I have had a similar problem, and wanted to try to determine a more compact solution.

I think the main culprit in this problem is that the pipe `|` operator doesn't let you specify the stream similar to how the redirect does e.g. `2>`.

The solution I have arrived at here is to chain the output of a number of subshells together, with the inner one processing `stdout` and then redirecting it to the alternative temporary stream `3`.

The next subshell redirects `stderr` into `stdin` again and repeats the activity of the inner shell (albeit prefixing with **"E:"** rather than **"O:"**). It redirects the output here to `stdout` again, though `>&2` could be removed if you *want* to have everything in `stdin` (but I think keeping these streams separate is an advantage).

The outer shell once more rejoins `&3` stream with `stdin`.

Since the two inner shells process `stdin` and `stdout` separately (because of the alternative "O:" and "E:" prefixes) it is necessary to run the `perl` command twice, so I have wrapped it up into a `fold` function to keep things tidy, and this is where the differing prefixes are also added.

You could probably do away with the `sed` and include that in the `perl` regex, and also be aware that a `\\n` is introduced at the end of each line by your `perl` command. In fact my personal opinion is that the line-folding introduced by this command shouldn't now be necessary but I retained it for fidelity with your original problem.

```
function fold {
    perl -pe 's,\n,\\n,'g | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/'${1}':\1\n/'
}

while read line ; do
    echo "C:$line"
    (
        (
            ${line} | fold O >&3
        ) 2>&1 | fold E >&2
    ) 3>&1 
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it's a clever idea to use subshells in this way.